# Kotlin : Copy File from Res directory to internal storage

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to Copy a file from my res directory to internal storage  and delete that file after closing my application with Kotlin.
There are some code in Java but my goal is reaching that with Kotlin programing.
How can I do that?
I searched The web but there are not Good tutorial for this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/how-to-copy-files-from-assets-folder-to-sdcard

Answer (score 1):

Read the file content from resources like:

```
val fileContent = MySpec::class.java.getResource("/myFiles/file.html").readText()
```

You can use this `copyTo` in Kotlin like:

```
 fun InputStream.copyTo(
    out: OutputStream,
    bufferSize: Int = DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE
): Long
```

This will Copies this stream to the given output stream, returning the number of bytes copied

**Note:** It is the caller's responsibility to close both of these resources.
Source: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-input-stream/copy-to.html

Delete it using:

```
val file = File(yourFIlePath)
file.absoluteFile.delete()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But it's not my answer. I don't want create a file. I have a file that i copied in my res folder and i wants to Copy that file to internal storage.

Comment: Java or Koltin but the syntax is different but the logic is the same ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm trying all this codes. But not worked in Kotlin project.

Comment: If you only say that it does not work you dont come further.